# Displaying Sub Report Data from First page only

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi I have designed a crystal report which has only two sub reports to be displayed and no fields on the main report.

I have created those two subreports and placed them on the main report's Report Header Section A and Section B respectively.

But the problem is when I execute the report, data is getting displayed properly from Second page but not from the first page. First page shows only blank data with header section printing. If I place some sample text fields on the same report header sections where my first sub report is placed, it is getting displayed on the first page only. But sub reports are not getting displayed from the first page.

Need a solution for the same

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the subreports in the report footer.

I've ran into problems with subreports in the report header that are longer than a page. I think this is due to the report header coming before the page header and maybe some bug.

Answer (score 1):

As DotJoe says, the recommendation is to put the sub reports into the footer sections when possible.  Due to the two pass nature of the reporting engine, not all values are calculated by the time the header is "printed", whereas everything is done by the time the footer is "printed".  I have seen some things such as Running Totals be zero in the header but a valid value in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the section expert (or format section in eralier versions), Add Page header section, it will generate two header and select the section that you want to hide on pages 1+ and find the "Suppress" option to the right of the tick box you will see the formula editor button, click that and in the formula editor add the following

PageNumber > 1

This will supress the section from printing on anything other than page 1 of your report.

Hope this helps,